# How to extract specific rows from an nd array in python

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, indexing

I have an array `b` which is of the shape `E x B x 3`. I have another array `a` which specifies which 3 elements to take our of `b`.

The following code works (in this example `E=2, B=4`):

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, 1, 0, 0]
b = np.array([[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0, 3.0]],
            [[2.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 0.0],  [0.0, 0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 0.0, 3.0]]])
# n_pred = np.transpose(n_pred, axes=[1, 0, 2])
c = []
for i, idx in enumerate(a):
    c.append(b[idx, i])
c = np.array(c)
print(c)
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to do this? (maybe using some built-in numpy function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index by the first two dimensions:

```
c = b[a, range(len(a))]

print(c)

array([[ 2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  3.]])
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something super simple that I was missing.